# Is there any way I can access Private member variable of a class?

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can access Private member variable of a class?

Editing:
Not from a member function or friend function but through an instance.

Comment: It was an interview quetions. I couldnt think of any way except doing som edirty trick with pointer manipulation. Taking the address of the object, offset of variable and then print it..But I was not sure if the offset of the varibale i could get correctly.

Comment: Who is this employer that's asking you to abuse your compiler?

Comment: The correct answer is "don't". You could declare a friend class to do this, but it's pretty poor design to do so.

Comment: Why do they ask interview questions on how to do things they should shoot you for?

Comment: To test your knowledge of how the compiler works inside, which is often an important thing to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast it around, shift memory and cast back. (didn't compile the code, but you should get the idea).

```
class Bla
{
public:
    Bla() : x(15), str("bla") {}
private:
    int x;
    std::string str;
}

int main()
{
    Bla bla;

    int x = *((int*)(&bla));
    std::string str = *((std::string*)((int*)(&bla) + 1));

    std::cout << x << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Since this is an interview question, I won't go into why you shouldn't do that. :)

EDIT: 
Classes with virtual functions will have virtual table pointer somewhere there as well. I'm not sure if & will give you address of vt or address of first data member.

Alignment is 4 by default (right?), so if member you are reading does not align, shift by 2 bytes to get to the next one.

Comment: It's possible for an optimizer to rearrange the allocation order of private members, so this isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: Where the virtual table pointer goes is implementation-dependent (the Standard doesn't even require one to exist, although everybody does it), and if there's public or protected members the compiler is allowed to mess with the variable order to some extent.

Answer (score 13):

[GotW #76](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) has fascinating language-lawyery details on how to do some of this stuff. :-)

Comment: That template trick is awesome, but needs the class to have something templated.

Comment: @Chris, ehh, can't beat you if you're referencing GotW :>

Answer (score 5):

One of the "dirty tricks" of C++ is to do something like:

```
#define private public
#include "ClassHeader.h"

// now all the private members of the included class are public
```

I **strongly do not recommend** that you do this.

Comment: Although you have added the disclaimer, some things just shouldn't be handed out... it makes it too easy for the crazy people to do it.

Comment: Section 17.4.3.1.1 of the C++ Standard: "Nor shall such a translation unit define macros for names lexically identical to keywords."  Of course, no known compiler rejects such programs.

Comment: Even for compilers that allow it, this violates ODR, and results in undefined behaviour. :-P

Comment: @Michael, and once the crazies reveal themselves we can get them the medications they need.

Comment: Heh.  Once I saw "#define const".

Answer (score 5):

You could:

1. Place the private members in the public section
2. Make your class or function a friend of the class.
3. Provide an accessor to the data.
4. Take the address of the class, add the offset to that variable, cast, and dereference. (Yuck)

What are you trying to do? If something is private, don't mess with it. It's private for a reason.

Comment: IMHO, the fourth one's the best :)

Comment: I remembered this story while reading your answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can access a private member:

- ...within other instances of the same (exact) type.
- ...within classes or functions declared to be a **friend** of that class.
- ...via a public accessor (getter/setter) member function.

Answer (score 2):

While we're proposing bad ideas, there is nothing on the code end which enforces encapsulation -- it's entirely a compiler trick -- so you can write assembly to directly access private members.

But why not just *rewrite the base class* if it isn't doing what you want already?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to?

Visibility rules are clear:

- private methods are to be accessed only by methods of the class
- protected methods can be accessed by methods of the class or descendants
- public methods can be accessed by anyone

... hence -- if you're writing the class yourself, choose the right visibility. If it's a supplied class, thing carefully **why** it was made private in the first place...

If you decide to break that rule however, you have several options:

- you can befriend the class that ought to access the private methods via a `friend` specifier
- you can use an ugly preprocessor hack that probably someone posted already, but do it **only** if you need to use the fields or methods to do unit-testing -- any other use is bad design
- you can use an ugly type-casting hack, but it's so ugly that I'm afraid to even post it not to get downvoted ;>

Comment: Anonymous cowardly down-voting?

Comment: Probably the OP. He seems to down-vote all the correct answers: "don't."

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not , through a member function

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how the question is phrased:

Q: How would you access a private member variable?
A: I wouldn't.

Along with:

Q: How would you implement ...
A: I wouldn't, it's already been done, I'd leverage an existing framework/library.

Interviewers don't always want to know if you can make a wheel, sometimes they are probing to see if you know how to find the nearest service station. :)